# Validating json data for unique fields in laravel

Tags: validation, unique

I have a json request with household_data. I have tried to use validator on family_no which is a unique field. the json I'm working on is :

```
 [
    {
       "BasicInfo": {
                "ward": "12",
                "tole_name": "Sahayogi Nagar",
                "house_no": "21",
                "family_no": "420",
                "district": "Lalitpur",
            },
            "Family": [
                {
                    "caste": "bahun",
                    "religion": "hindu",
                }
            ]
}]
```

But the validator fails always, even if the family_no is unique or not and returns:

```
{
    "family_no": [
        "The family no field is required."
    ]
}
```

here is my controller code:

```
$items = json_decode($request->household_data);
        // return json_decode($request->household_data);
        if($request->household_data){
            $validator = Validator::make($items, [
                'family_no' => 'required|unique:households|max:255',
            ]);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return response()->json($validator->errors(), 404);
            }

            else{
                foreach($items as $key=>$item){
                    $householdId = $this->saveHousehold($item);
                    return $householdId;
                }
            }

        }
```

Anyone could please help me validate the unique field family_no?

Answer (score 0):

checkout array validator of laravel on the doc webiste https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#validating-arrays. But for your validation you have to write it like this :

```
{
    "BasicInfo.family_no": [
        "The family no field is required."
    ]
}
```